# Several keys on my ASUS desktop keyboard are not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, asus, keyboard-layout

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my ASUS G10AC, several keys on my keyboard (ASUS G01 KB) are not working at all.  This includes both CTRL keys, both ALT keys, and both WINDOWS keys.  When I use the keyboard layout utility I can see that pressing the CTRL and ALT keys correspond to using the left SHIFT key, whereas none of the WINDOWS keys gives any sort of response (no key is highlighted).  I would like to know how to activate the proper function to these keys.